# Clojure - sequence of objects

Tags: variables, clojure, type-conversion, sequence

I have a Clojure function:

```
(def obseq
  (fn []
    (let [a 0
          b 1
          c 2]
      (println (seq '(a b c))))))
```

It outputs :

```
(a b c)
```

I want it to output a sequence containing the values of a, b, and c, not their names.

Desired output:

```
(1 2 3)
```

How do I implement this?

Answer (score 5):

### Short answer:

```
clj.core=> (defn obseq [] 
             (let [a 0 
                   b 1 
                   c 2]
               (println [a b c])))
#'clj.core/obseq
clj.core=> (obseq)
[0 1 2]
nil
```

### Long answer:

Quoting a form like `'(a b c)` ***recursively prevents*** any evaluation inside the quoted form.  So, the values for your 3 symbols `a`, `b`, and `c` aren't substituted.  It is much easier to use a vector (square brackets), which never needs to be quoted (unlike a list).  Since the vector is unquoted, the 3 symbols are evaluated and replaced by their values.

If you wanted it to stay a list for some reason, the easiest way is to type:

```
clj.core=> (defn obseq [] (let [a 0 b 1 c 2] (println (list a b c))))
#'clj.core/obseq
clj.core=> (obseq)
(0 1 2)
nil
```

This version also has no quoting, so the 3 symbols are replaced with their values. Then the function `(list ...)` puts them into a list data structure.

Note that I also converted your `(def obseq (fn [] ...))` into the preferred form `(defn obseq [] ...)`, which has the identical result but is shorter and (usually) clearer.